# PDO binding values for MySQL IN statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-in

I have an issue with PDO that I'd really like to get an answer for after being plagued by it for quite some time.

Take this example:

I am binding an array of ID's to a PDO statement for use in a MySQL IN statement.

The array would be say: **$values = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);**

The database-safe variable would be **$products = implode(',' $values);**

So, **$products** would then be a *STRING* with a value of: **'1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8'**

The statement would look like:

```
SELECT users.id
FROM users
JOIN products
ON products.user_id = users.id
WHERE products IN (:products)
```

Of course, **$products** would be bound to the statement as **:products**.

However, when the statement is compiled and values bound, it would actually look like this:

```
SELECT users.id
FROM users
JOIN products
ON products.user_id = users.id
WHERE products IN ('1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8')
```

The problem is it is executing everything inside of the IN statement as a single string, given that I've prepared it as comma-separated values to bind to the statement.

What I actually need is:

```
SELECT users.id
FROM users
JOIN products
ON products.user_id = users.id
WHERE products IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
```

The only way I can actually do this is by placing the values within the string itself without binding them, however I know for certain there has to be an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is the same thing as was asked in this question:  [Can I bind an array to an IN() condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition)

The answer there was that, for a variable sized list in the `in` clause, you'll need to construct the query yourself.

**However,** you can use the quoted, comma-separated list using [`find_in_set`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), though for large data sets, this would have considerable performance impact, since every value in the table has to be cast to a char type.

For example:

```
select users.id
from users
join products
on products.user_id = users.id
where find_in_set(cast(products.id as char), :products)
```

**Or, as a third option,** you could create a user defined function that splits the comma-separated list for you (cf. http://www.slickdev.com/2008/09/15/mysql-query-real-values-from-delimiter-separated-string-ids/).  This is probably the best option of the three, especially if you have a lot of queries that rely on `in(...)` clauses.

Comment: Geez, PDO is such a neat library yet misses some of the most basic functionalities. Bit of a shame really..

Comment: If you have a small set of data, you might be able to get away with find_in_set (I updated the answer with an example), or you might try a user-defined function to parse the comma-separated list for you.  (Sorry to keep adding ideas, ha ha; after I posted the link to the other question, I thought, "there's got to be a way to do that...")

Comment: Thanks for the FIND_IN_SET heads-up. Really saved my day. But I found that it works without having to do a CAST, so find_in_set(products.id, :products) is enough.

Comment: A very useful answer. Can you add a version of this answer to the question you linked to? Seeing as it's got more votes and is more likely to come up at the top of search results.

Comment: I will just add one thing: when you bind param :products to the string, it CAN NOT HAVE any whitespaces e.g. `1,2,3,4` is correct but `1, 2, 3, 4` is NOT.

Answer (score 28):

A good way to handle this situation is to use [`str_pad`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) to place a `?` for every value in the SQL query. Then you can pass the array of values (in your case `$values`) as the argument to execute:

```
$sql = '
SELECT users.id
FROM users
JOIN products
ON products.user_id = users.id
WHERE products.id IN ('.str_pad('',count($values)*2-1,'?,').')
';

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute($values);
$user_ids = $sth->fetchAll();
```

This way you get more benefit from using prepared statements rather than inserting the values directly into the SQL.

PS - The results will return duplicate user ids if the products with the given ids share user ids. If you only want unique user ids I suggest changing the first line of the query to `SELECT DISTINCT users.id`

Comment: Why is it needed to do `*2-1` rather than just `-1` on the `count()`?

Comment: @Nalum: Because str_pad's 2nd parameter is the "pad length" which is in characters. Since you want a question mark for each value and a comma in between them, that works out to be `count($values)*2-1`. You could alternatively use something like `str_repeat('?,',count($values)-1).'?'` if you want.

Comment: I prefer to use `implode(',', array_fill(1,count($values),'?'))` because there's less chance of off-by-one errors, and you don't have to handle the last element differently.

Comment: you can also use str_repeat() for this, it's probably the most efficient of the listed methods: `rtrim( str_reapeat('?,', count($values)), ',')`

Comment: When is putting variables directly inside a query ever a good idea?  Did we really fight for SQL injection countermeasures to have 17 votes on a solution advocating what one really shouldn't do?

Comment: @Dominique You are reading the code wrong. It does not put variables directly inside the query. That is really the point of the solution. It puts a "?" for every variable so that PDO can prepare the actual statement. Yes we like PDO's safeguards, and this solution presents a way to use them.

Comment: `implode(',', array_fill(0, count($values), '?'))`

Answer (score 10):

The best prepared statement you could probably come up with in a situation like this is something resembling the following:

```
SELECT users.id
FROM users
JOIN products
ON products.user_id = users.id
WHERE products IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

You would then loop through your values and bind them to the prepared statement making sure that there are the same number of question marks as values you are binding.

Comment: Logical solution when you know how many variables to bind but it gets a bit messy when you have an indefinite number of parameters.

Comment: @hd82: Well, then you have to smartly combine sprintf and count.

Answer (score 10):

you need to provide same number of **?s** in **IN** as the number of values in your **$values** array

this can be done easily by creating an array of ?s as

```
 $in = join(',', array_fill(0, count($values), '?'));
```

and use this $in array in your IN clause

THis will dynamically provide you with tailor made array of **?s** as per your changiing $values array

Answer (score 3):

You can do so very easily.
If you have an array of values for your IN() statement
EG:

```
$test = array(1,2,3);
```

You can simply do

```
$test = array(1,2,3);
$values = count($test);
$criteria = sprintf("?%s", str_repeat(",?", ($values ? $values-1 : 0)));
//Returns ?,?,?
$sql = sprintf("DELETE FROM table where column NOT IN(%s)", $criteria);
//Returns DELETE FROM table where column NOT IN(?,?,?)
$pdo->sth = prepare($sql);
$pdo->sth->execute($test);
```

Comment: This was already mentioned on Asaph's answer above, and doesn't work if you're using named parameters, since you can't mix them.

Answer (score 1):

If the expression is based on user input without binding the values with bindValue(), experimental SQL might not be a great choice. *But*, you can make it safe by checking the syntax of the input with MySQL's REGEXP.

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id IN (3,156)
AND '3,156' REGEXP '^([[:digit:]]+,?)+$'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of binding an unknown number of record columns to values for an insert.

```
public function insert($table, array $data)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table (" . join(',', array_keys($data)) . ') VALUES ('
        . str_repeat('?,', count($data) - 1). '?)';

    if($sth = $this->db->prepare($sql))
    {
        $sth->execute(array_values($data));
        return $this->db->lastInsertId();
    }
}

$id = $db->insert('user', array('name' => 'Bob', 'email' => 'foo@example.com'));
```

Answer (score -4):

Please try like this:

```
WHERE products IN(REPLACE(:products, '\'', ''))
```

Regards

Comment: This question was asked and answered 5 years ago, and this answer does not solve the problem..