# How to protect against SQL injection with an IN() array?

Tags: php, mysql, get

How I can protect my code from SQL injections? I have URL like this:

```
example.com/players.php?ids=100098,131183,188736,261945,301588
```

and query

```
$ids = (isset($_GET['ids'])) ? $_GET['ids'] : false;
$query = "SELECT * FROM player WHERE profileid IN (". $ids .")";
```

Comment: i can't found answer in that thread, why you closed?

Comment: You can't use parameter binding with an array, only single values. `explode()` on the comma, cast each element to int, and then `implode()` using a comma again.

Comment: That said, you can use parameter binding if you are happy to programmatically create the placeholders in your SQL string. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11405602/472495), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/920353/472495) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1586587/472495).

Comment: Any example with non PDO?

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: xampp 1.6.8 on localhost, yes it bit old.

Comment: I meant database library. MySQL (deprecated `mysql_`) or MySQLi?

Comment: I got answer on other forum. Question can be closed!