# MySQL IN() to work with PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP PDO: Can I bind an array to an IN() condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition)

I have only made websites with PHP and MySQL for a hobby, my whole life I've always used unprepared statements until I decided to try PDO queries last night. I've successfuly gotten them all to work except when I use IN(). For Example when i do this:

```
$stmt3 = $dbConnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM member_search WHERE zip IN(:zip_codes_in_distance)");
$stmt3->execute(array(':zip_codes_in_distance' =>   $zip_codes_in_distance ));
foreach ($stmt3 as $user_list) {
   //do cool stuff here
}
```

This returns this error:

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1064
```

After googling it, I've tried with no success a few of the solutions like using `query()` instead of `execute()`

This only happens when I use `IN()`

the `$zip_codes_in_distance` are zipcodes in this format '07110', '07109', '07050'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition

Comment: Hmm, I did not find that link even while typing in the title to my question, thank you, looking at it now.

Comment: I had faced a similar issue and found the solutions in this answer quite useful. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1586650

Comment: So this is an array problem. Ok, going to convert my query now with these solutions and see if I can get it to work, I'll comment back with a result shortly, thank you both for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't get this to work correctly using PDO, so I used MySQLi instead.
Establish Database Connection in a separate file:

```
$Connect = new mysqli($host, DB_Username, DB_password, DB_Name);
```

Ran the Query like this:

```
include 'DbConnectFIle.php';
$zips = "07110, 07109";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE zip IN(".$zips.") ";
        $result = $Connect->query($sql);
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                     $MemberName = $row['first_name'];
        }
$Connect->close();

echo $MemberName;
```

Tried for four hours using PDO, MySQLi was the only way I could get it to work. 
I used this tutorial: http://codular.com/php-mysqli