# mysql pdo security issue

Tags: php, mysql

Collecting the data from query string

```
$cat_id=$_GET['cat_id']; // Actual 

$cat_id="'2','3'"; // Sample data format required

$sql="select * from table_name where cat_id IN ($cat_id)";

foreach ($dbo->query($sql) as $row) {

    $str=$str . "$row[subcat]".",";

}
```

As I am collecting data from the query string and I had to use in that format ( 2nd line ) how can I prevent injection attack here ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

If there are only numbers came from `$_GET`, then here is an *easy workaround*, which forcing each member type of `$cat_id` subset to be integer:

```
$cat_id = implode(
    ',',
    array_map(
        function($v){ return (int)$v; },
        explode(',', $cat_id)
    );
);
```

It will split `$cat_id` to array `['1','2']` with [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) function, then converts each member to an integer with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array-map) and joining array back to string with a comma (`,`) as separator by [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode). Result would be: `'1,2'`.

However, I would like to suggest to read through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). If you using pdo, then you may just try to use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function instead of `IN` with parameter binding. Related questions:

1. [PDO binding values for MySQL IN statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586587/pdo-binding-values-for-mysql-in-statement)
2. [PHP PDO: Can I bind an array to an IN() condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition)

Comment: The only problem with `FIND_IN_SET ()` is that the optimizer will scan the entire table to evaluate every row, since it doesn't realize the potential exists to transform the expression into something it can resolve using indexes.