# how to search array of checkboxes

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox, get

Im building a search form but how do you search a array of checkboxes?

here is my html form

```
<form method="get">
<label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="material[]" value="metal">metal
</label>
<label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="material[]" value="plastic">Plastic
</label>
<label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="material[]" value="carbon">Carbon
</label>
<input type="text" name="keyword">
<input type="submit" value="search">
</form>
```

and the php so far is. So how can i search the material for each checked.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['keyword'])){
$keyword = $_GET['keyword'];
// $material = $_GET['material'];
// $Search->search($keyword);
}
?>
```

ANd the query would be so far

```
$query = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `shop` WHERE `material` = ?');
```

Comment: Use a `foreach` http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: First of all fix your `value`s.

Comment: yeah but how would you search the query with a foreach

Answer (score 1):

When posted this will submit an array named `material` (accessible via `$_GET['material']`) that contains only the values that were checked.

You can then use those or output them like this:

```
foreach ($_GET['material'] AS $material) {
  echo $material;
}
```

Addition after the question was edited:
You can also `implode()` the array values with `', '` as glue and use that as the search parameter in your SQL statement. Just change it to use `IN` instead of `=`, like @Prashant M Bhavsar suggested in his answer.

Comment: with the implode and the strings you are not really using the binding of PDO, which is why you are using this...

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you

Get your submitted material array in variable

```
$material_array = $_POST['material'];
```

You can implode array in select query to fetch related result

```
 $selected_search_material = implode(',', $material_array);
    SELECT * FROM `shop` WHERE `material` IN ($selected_search_material)
```

Comment: where is the explanation and help?

Comment: @RichardBernards..can you please suggest me whats the wrong answer i have posted..it will help me to improve..Thanks

Comment: You are just pasting some code... How does this solve the OP's problem?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this yet, but since you receive an array (`$_get['material']` is already an array), just use the following code with [find_in_set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586587/pdo-binding-values-for-mysql-in-statement);

```
<?php
$materials = array();
if (array_key_exists('material', $_GET)) {
    $materials = $_GET['material'];
}

$query = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `shop` WHERE find_in_set(cast(material as char), :materials');
$query->execute(array('materials' => $materials));

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Implode `$_GET['material']` and use a different query:

```
$where = implode(', ',$_GET['material']);
$query = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `shop` WHERE `material` IN ?');
```

Then use `$where` in your `execute()`;

Answer (score -1):

You can use $materialValue to store into Database.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['material'])){
    $material = $_GET['material'];
    foreach($material as $materialIndex){
         $materialValue .= $materialIndex.',';
    }
}

// use value to store into db
```

pass $materialValue variable to IN query also remove last "," from string

```
$materialValue.substring(0,$materialValue.length()-1);
?>
```

Comment: `$materialIndex` is a value, not an index... Try naming your variables better. Second; at the end of the loop, `$materialValue` will only contain the last value of the array... Not a desired effect

Comment: Now there is a comma at the end which breaks SQL queries using IN

Comment: No, You will get all values not only last one.

Comment: so i could use the IN query using this? Or will it not working because of the last ',' at the end?

Comment: @DanielLe please don't try to use this code... It's a bad example if you want to learn something

Comment: @DanielLe You know the last few lines are pseudocode and not PHP, right? I urge you to have a look at my answer...