# PDO Union Where and In

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$prepare=$text->prepare("
  select *
  from (
    select text1,text2
    from test1
  union
    select text1,text2
    from test2
  ) as u
  where u.text1 in (?,?)");
$prepare->execute($array);
$fetch=$prepare->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($fetch);
```

I have a PDO statement that uses UNION, WHERE and IN all in one. This should be returning a few results. The array contains all datapoints. What might be the issue in the statement?

Answer (score 0):

In prepared statements, in IN clause you need to construct the query yourself. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586587/pdo-binding-values-for-mysql-in-statement) for more information.
If you got an error, please edit your post and include the error msg.

EDIT:

```
//Correct use of fetch statement:
$prepare->execute($array);
$results = array();
while( $fetch=$prepare->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ){
    $results[] = $fetch;
}
print_r($results);
```

Comment: Ok. But I tried testing out without IN. Just doing "select * from (select text1,text2 from test1) as u" and I only got 1 result when there are over 8 in the database.

Comment: How many rows do you get trying only with "select text1,text2 from test1" ?

Comment: Do you get only one row trying from php or from mysql console? You are using the fetch statement incorrectly

Comment: I just realized I am using "fetch" instead of "fetchall"