# PHP / SQL Select list of id from DB and use it in query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi i made a page on my website to find quest in my database.

The method i used for now, its working but i have to update it everytime.

```
$demande = "SELECT * FROM quest_quest WHERE id IN (584,585,586,587,589,599,601,617,608,615,616) LIMIT ".(($cPage-1)*$perPage).",$perPage";
```

instead i would like to query my database and use the id in my query

I have a table with TagID and IDquest, i want to make a query to hold all questid and use it on my query

Example:

```
$questsfind = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `quest_statetag` WHERE idTag ='8'");
```

I want to have a variable like that (221, 587, 1155, 1255, 5585)

```
$demande = "SELECT * FROM quest_quest WHERE id IN ('".$questsfind."') LIMIT ".(($cPage-1)*$perPage).",$perPage";
```

nb: Sry for my english its not my mother tongue :S

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1586650/3166303

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understand the question, but I believe you are looking to hold a bunch of IDs in a variable (from a query) and then create another query from that?

```
$first = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quest_quest WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4)");

if( ! $first )
    die('Something went wrong...');

$ids = array();

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($first) ) {
    $ids[] = $row['id'];
}

$query_ids = implode(',', $ids);

$second = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quest_statetag WHERE idTag IN ($query_ids)");
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: How i can query my DB to have all the ID in the array ?

$TagQueryAray0 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `quest_statetag` WHERE idTag ='8'");

This return me only one ID normaly the result should give me 25 id and more

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Are you trying to save the array of IDs to the database? The answer I posted would essentially return any result with one of those IDs...

Comment: $TagQueryAray0 = array();
  $TagQueryAray0 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `quest_statetag` WHERE idTag ='8'");
  $query_ids = implode(',', $TagQueryAray0);
  $demande = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quest_quest WHERE id IN ($query_ids)");

Comment: I want to query a sql table to get ID of quests and use it in other query

Comment: Modified my answer. See above

Answer (score 1):

first you have to convert your associative array to string

`$questsfinds = implode(',', $questsfind);`

Then you can try FIND_IN_SET method

`SELECT * FROM quest_quest WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id,'$questsfinds');`