# Using IN() condition in PDO MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to search a value in a mysql table field. using prepared statements.

services: 2,4,5

passed value: 2

```
$query = "SELECT *
          FROM table
          WHERE services IN(':array')"
```

so basically I'm trying to return all rows where 2 is inside the services field. The field itself will have numbers separated by commas. So the services field can look like this: 2,3,6,7,1 or just something like this: 4.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/14767530/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/1586587/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/920353/ should get you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT *
          FROM table
          WHERE FIND_IN_SET(':array', services )"
```

:array is 2 what u want pass.

Comment: I suggest you test this first.

Comment: If I just want I pass one value like an integer do I still use :array?