# Mysql SELECT WHERE $VAR IN $VAR,$VAR,$VAR

Tags: php, mysql, select

Can anybody see how i can use a String instead of Numeral for this Statement,

Im trying to pull all rows with $delivery when $delivery="ALL" but i can only pull 1 single Variable, if i want to pull an array, i cannot , because i get Array conversion num to string,

```
$delivery_con = [];
if ($delivery==="collection") { $delivery_con[]="no";}
if ($delivery==="delivery") {$delivery_con[]="yes";}
if ($delivery==="local") {$delivery_con[]="yes local";}

if ($delivery==="either") {$delivery_con=["no","yes","yes local"];}


$query="SELECT * 
        FROM testdata 
        WHERE title LIKE ? 
        AND location LIKE ? 
        AND postcode LIKE ? 
        AND price >=? 
        AND price <=? 
        AND cond=? 
        AND catagory LIKE ? 
        AND delivery IN ? 
        ORDER BY $order $dir";

$stat=$db->prepare($query);

$stat->execute(array("%$searchfor%",
                    "%$location%",
                    "%$postcode%",
                    "$pricefrom",
                    "$priceto",
                    "$cond",
                    "%$catagory%",
                    "$delivery_con"));
```

So my question is, how can a get around this for the select function to work with $variables,

Im really stuck. If anybody can help

Thank you.

Comment: Rather than using the placeholder `?` have you tried putting the variable directly into the statement like so: `{$delivery_con}` ? Also why does `$delivery_con` need to be an array?

Comment: You have to write a small piece of code that transforms your array into a string with proper format for the `IN` operator in your select.  Look at that syntax requirements, then build the string from a loop on the array.  Like @MCMXCII pointed out below.

Comment: This might be of assistance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586587/pdo-binding-values-for-mysql-in-statement.

Comment: ok thank you, il look into your info, thanks

Comment: Needs to be an array because in the database, i have YES, NO , YES LOCAL, and i need all rows with either of them to be listed if the user should choose to view all of them... But the statment will only pull the chosen variable and not all 3. i have to make a seperate query to get it working is $delivery="either" / query2 - But iv got other forms with the same sort of issue to sort too, so i need a statment that will pull all rows if either selected

Comment: `"$delivery_con"` the quotes makes the array a string, remove those

Comment: Adobe Cold Fusion is the only app framework I've heard of that offers native binding of arrays to `IN()` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

When working with IN() SQL operator, you need create a set of `?`  manually and put them into the query:

```
<?php

$delivery_con = [];

if ($delivery === "collection") {
    $delivery_con[] = "no";
}
if ($delivery === "delivery") {
    $delivery_con[] = "yes";
}
if ($delivery === "local") {
    $delivery_con[] = "yes local";
}

if ($delivery==="either") {$delivery_con=["no","yes","yes local"];}


$in = str_repeat('?,', count($delivery_con) - 1) . '?';


$searchfor = "%$searchfor%";
$location  = "%$location%";
$postcode  = "%$postcode%";
$catagory  = "%$catagory%";

$array1 = array($searchfor,$location,$postcode,$pricefrom,$priceto,$cond,$catagory);

$params = array_merge($array1, $delivery_con);

$query = "SELECT * 
        FROM testdata 
        WHERE title LIKE ? 
        AND location LIKE ? 
        AND postcode LIKE ? 
        AND price >=? 
        AND price <=? 
        AND cond=? 
        AND catagory LIKE ? 
        AND delivery IN ($in) 
        ORDER BY $order $dir";

$stat = $db->prepare($query);

$stat->execute([$params]);
```

Comment: if ($delivery==="either") {$delivery_con="no,yes,yes local";}


$query="SELECT * FROM testdata WHERE title LIKE ? AND location LIKE ? AND postcode LIKE ? AND price >=? AND price <=? AND cond=? AND catagory LIKE ? AND delivery IN (?) ORDER BY $order $dir";

$stat=$db->prepare($query);

$stat->execute(array("%$searchfor%","%$location%","%$postcode%","$pricefrom","$priceto","$cond","%$catagory%",$delivery_con));

Comment: But it wont display all rows for ["no,yes,yes local"], just the others....

Comment: Have you tried to run the query without the placeholders?

Comment: no, its a prepared statment , im not sure if i can, il try it.

Comment: @MelissaHicking ofcoz you can for testing puporses

Comment: im not sure how i would write it using {$var} instead of (?).

Comment: Simple but a variable instead of ?

Comment: sorry, im trying your code now..

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in D:\xampp\htdocs\Vbay\html\Vbaymain.php on line 809

Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in D:\xampp\htdocs\Vbay\html\Vbaymain.php on line 809.. I DID ADD the $priceto & $pricefrom to the list of vars, but still getting the same error