# I need the output of this $LoadId=implode(',',array_filter($_POST["load"])); to look like this ('7209','7210')

Tags: php, sql-server

SO i get data from a form using this

```
$LoadId=implode(',',array_filter($_POST["load"]));
```

I then would like to submit this to a MSSQL query with an "in" statement

```
where myLoadId in $LoadId
```

but the $LoadID looks like 7209,7210 and I need it to look like 
('7209','7210')

Comment: `where myLoadId in ($LoadId)`.. but you need to prevent sql injections so `where myLoadId in ?` would be the correct suggestion.

Comment: not 100% dupe - but I'd heavily recommend switching to PDO for use of prepared statements https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586587/pdo-binding-values-for-mysql-in-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your `LoadId` column contains interger value so why you need single quotes `'` around it? Simply use-

```
$LoadId=implode(',',array_filter($_POST["load"]));
$query = "SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE myLoadId IN ($LoadId)";
echo $query;
```

If you still need quotes around it then you can do it this way-

```
$LoadId = "'".implode("','", array_filter($_POST["load"]))."'";
$query = "SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE myLoadId IN ($LoadId)";
echo $query;
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/2XEjJ

Answer (score 0):

Put simple quotes around the `implode()` and change it's glue from `,` to `','` :

```
$LoadId = "'".implode("','", array_filter($_POST["load"]))."'";
```